# How do I use sed to replace <h1>...</h1> with <h2>...</h2>

Tags: regex, sed

I can actually do the leading `<h1>` with this:

```
sed s/\<h1\>/\<h2\>/ myblog.html
```

but how do I get it to do the trailing `</h1>` also?

So I would like to go from:

```
<h1> some header </h1> to <h2> some header </h2>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the slash when defining sed substition commands, it can be another symbol:

```
sed -e 's/<h1>/<h2>/g' -e 's_</h1>_</h2>_g'
```

Comment: Or `sed -e 's/<h1>/<h2>/g;s_</h1>_</h2>_g'`

Answer (score 1):

Use capturing group to capture the optional `/` and replace by back-reference the capturing group:

```
sed -r 's/<(\/?)h1>/<\1h2>/' myblog.html
```

`-r` option is to activate extended regular expression.

Comment: @woollybrain: Forgot that `(` doesn't have special meaning in sed regex

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I find the simplest solution for HTML tags is to ignore the slash in the closing tag altogether and match the open and close together with a single pattern, like this:

```
sed 's/h1>/h2>/' myblog.html
```